# i can't wrap in flutter It was wrap before, I don't know what it looked like

Tags: flutter, api, dart, mobile-application, diamond-problem

I can't wrap in flutter It was wrap before, I don't know what it looked like

[image]

It's manual without rap is difficult and time consuming

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? I don't understand anything what do you need

Comment: Why did you tag this `diamond-problem`?